# Set html form value - TEdgeBrowser in Delphi 10.4

Tags: javascript, html, delphi

I am using Delphi 10.4 and the EdgeBrowser component.
I am loading below html form.

```
 EdgeBrowser1.navigate('http: //localhost/form.html');
```

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input id="email" type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am trying to set the value of the name field as follows.

```
  var Script: string := 'window.getElementById("name").value = 100';
  EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript(Script);
```

However, to no avail. What am I doing wrong ?
How can I:

a) set the value of a field

b) execute Submit

Comment: What do you see in the console logs?

Comment: How can I add/run console log under EdgeBrowser ?

Comment: The fastest way I use, is to right-click anywhere on the page and in the context menu click Inspect.  Then go into the console tab.

Comment: There are not any error.

Comment: Then you have to look at the source html produced to see if everything is there.  Do you see `window.getElementById("name").value = 100` anywhere?

Comment: No, I see only HTML code. I didint see JS code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220758/discussion-between-dominique-fortin-and-olaf).

Comment: `getElementById` is not a method of `window` instance but rather `document` instance. Use `document.getElementById("name")` instead.

Comment: Bingo!. Many Thanks @Peter. SO, how can I execute submit button ?

Comment: But that's another question and it's related to Javascript. Anyway you would need to call [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method of submit button. If it doesn't have an ID you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to look it up: `document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").click();`

Comment: You can also call [`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) or [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) on the form element.